# Should "censorship" and "book-banning" tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Should "[censorship](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship)" and "[book-banning](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-banning)" tags be synonyms? I'd propose the latter as a synonym of the former, since censorship is a wider term, which wholly encompasses book banning.

Comment: I think it is bit early to be talking about tag synonyms.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - this question arose out of practice. We have questions ALREADY posted with both tags

Comment: What [tag:book-banning] tag? ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - was it banned?

Comment: @DVK I censored it :-P

Comment: It is [banned-books].not [book-banning].

Answer (score 13):

**No.** Banned books and censored books are actually quite different. Books can be censored without being banned, for a wide range of reasons.

For example, see Anne Frank's diary: a book that's widely taught, but from which certain sections have been removed pretty much everywhere it's taught in schools. (Particularly at the non-collegiate level.) Additionally, there's also censorship by suppression, which happens all too often.

Banned books have much different historical contexts from censorship, as well, making them quite a unique category. While tools such as banned books list fall categorically under censorship, back in the 17th and 18th centuries, they had very different meanings than they do now. Often, academics would put each others' books on banned books lists, not as a form of intentional censorship, but as a form of slander.

Comment: But the question is if banning isn't a *subset* on censorship.

Comment: @Christian What I'm saying is, even though one is the subset of the other, they're different categories, and have different implications. I'll expand.

Comment: @ChristianRau books can be banned for copyright reasons, which isn't necessarily censorship.